# angular libraries and git workflow

Tags: angularjs, git, workflow

I'm developing angular libraries with a tool called ng-packagr

When building a library you may have multiple projects using this library.
What would be the git workflow used when you develop such libraries with ng-packagr or any library ?

For example you have a lib-1.0.0 developed with agular 4.x.
This lib-1.0.0 is used by clients cl_1 and cl_2.

Now what happens when you want the same library to work with angular 5.
Then I suposse your new library will be called lib-2.0.0 developed with angular 5.x giving the same functionality for clients that also use angular 5.
This lib-2.0.0 is used by clients cl_3 and cl_4.

Now my question is: What would be the best way to structure a git repository and what would be its workflow for a library like the ones like lib-1.0.0 and lib-2.0.0 ?

should lib-1.0.0 and lib-2.0.0 be in the same git repo.

master -----------------------------------------
\
branch 1 lib-1.0.0 (angular4.x)------------------------
\
branch 2 lib-2.0.0 (angular5.x)

Here I have one repo and two branches.
branch 1 will be for the library that uses angular 4.x and branch 2 will be for the library that uses angualr 5.x

Both libraries do the same functionality and the only difference should be the version of angular
If a bug appears in lib-1.0.0 how should it be handled ?
Should it be solved in lib-1.0.0 and then ported to lib-2.0.0 ?
We can never merge both branches to master because one is for angular 4.x and the other for angular 5.x.

This article is explaining a workflow for applications using git called git flow.
Here is the link http://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html.
Basically the questions boil to how to incorporate those ideas to the libraries taken into account my prior questions ?
How do the angular guys deal with the angular itself and how do they handle versions ?

If you ahve thoughts about it please share them. I think they would be very interesting.
thanks

Or should we have two different repos for the same library ?

Comment: I suggest two repositories since AngularJS and Angular 2+ are not different versions of a single framework. Also they require different development tools so contributors should not need to install both.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your answer  Aluan Haddad
I'm developing a library that uses angular(2, 3, 4, 5 ...). The difference between angular 4 and 5 is not mayor and the package.json of the library will specify different versions respectively. Thats one difference. The second difference would be certain imports for example HTTP will be renamed to HTTPClient from v4 to v5. But it is still the same language. Like you said its the same framework. But for v4 of the library I could have bug fixes that I have to port to v5 or viceversa because the library would offer the same functionality no matter if its v4 or v5. The same if new features for v4 come in I will have to add them to v5. The main question then is if with two repos one for v4 and the other for v5 this is easier to do than instead of having one repo and multiple branches for each version. Basically its having a git flow for libraries where we need to keep v4 and v5 alive until there are no more clients using them or until they  become deprecated. Also the development tools will not be shipped with the libraries. The client will have to install them. The libraries will only contain the code that implements the functionality.